# WordPress Custom Query for Taxonomy

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, post

I have to edit somebody's code and I am not familiar with querying posts using the method they are. I have tried editing the query to various alternatives, however I am having no luck. I want to change the following query to select data from a custom taxonomy called 'job_cat' where the value equals a POST value. The code is below:

```
$querystr = "
SELECT DISTINCT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2 ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 94";
// If a job type is set and not equal to nothing or any jobs


if(isset($_POST['search-location']) && $_POST['search-location'] !== "" &&     $_POST['search-location'] !== "All") {
    $querystr .= " AND (wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'region' AND wpostmeta2.meta_value     = '".$_POST['search-location']."')";
}
    $querystr .= " ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 50";

//Execute
//echo $querystr;
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($querystr, OBJECT));
```

Any help would be great!!

Comment: **WARNING:** *Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack!*  Read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) for more information.

Comment: I suppose you use custom query, not WP_Query class. Can you confirm that `wpostmeta` is the name of your table ?

Comment: Where's the rest of the query string? You haven't shared the part before `AND`.

Comment: @mevius I have added the rest of the code, thanks!

Comment: This is 100% wrong - don't do SQL stuff in your PHP. You need to use the WP functions.

Answer (score 0):

**This code is extremely dangerous to use in a production WordPress site.** You need to remove it and any other template file larded up with SQL queries like this.

Instead, use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) which automatically sanitizes your SQL requests. It has a huge number of parameters you can set to query anything from WordPress. Here is an example using `WP_Query` to get posts by a given taxonomy, with `tax_query`.

```
<?php
// 1- Setup an argument to give to WP_Query
$taxonomy_args = array(
  // 2- use the tax_query to examine a taxonomy
  'tax_query' => array(
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'job_cat',
        'terms' => 'XYZ',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'include_children' => true,
        'operator' => 'IN'
     )
  ),
  // 3- Make sure to define how many posts and what post-type they should be
  'posts_per_page' => 50,
  'post_type' => 'search-location',
);

$s = new WP_Query( $some_args );

if ( $s->have_posts() ) : $s->the_post();
    // 4- Here you will manipulate the data you get back
endif;
?>
```